# Most efficient way to re encode H.264 10-Bit to High profile or HEVC 10-Bit

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, h.264, h.265

For an odd reason my OLED TV can play HEVC 10-Bit files but only H.264 non-10-Bit.

This output (video stream) from ffmpeg is played fine with HEVC 10-Bit:

> `Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)`

while this file won't play:

> `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)`

and this encode seems to be the max that will work on my TV:

> `Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)`

I use the following command to convert to HEVC:

`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:4 -vcodec hevc -preset ultrafast -x265-params lossless=1 -acodec copy -scodec copy out.mkv`

That of course takes a while and require the lossless switch or video gets extremely pixelated. I tried to look at `hevc_nvenc` but it said “no compatible devices” (maybe need to provide more info for it, I have an NVIDIA GeForce 980 TI).

Also tried using `-vcodec h264` with `-preset high` and got an error saying:

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Any encoding gurus able to help with faster conversion to HEVC or conversion to a lower preset of H.264, or help getting NVENC to work if it provides significant performance gains…?

Answer (score 2):

TVs are sometimes very picky about what profiles and levels they support for a given codec.

In any case, you should not have to resort to lossless encoding to retain quality when converting from H.264 to H.265. Please read the [H.265 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for the available options w.r.t. quality and conversion speed.

While setting the `ultrafast` preset will definitely improve the overall speed of the encode, it'll significantly increase the file size (when using a constant quality encoding mode) or decrease the video quality (when using a target bitrate).

For HEVC, this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -preset fast <output>
```

Decrease the CRF value to increase the quality. A value of ±6 should result in half or double the bitrate, but it'll depend on the complexity of the content you're encoding.

> I tried to look at hevc_nvenc but it said no compatible devices (maybe need to provide more info to it, I have 980Ti)

The 980 TI [supports `NVENC`](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix) (see complete list).

Generally though, once you have a compatible device, in order to get support for `hevc_nvenc`, the NVIDIA libraries have to be installed on your system, and your `ffmpeg` needs to be compiled with support for `nvenc`. See [this wiki entry](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#NVENC) for more info.

> conversion to a lower preset of h264

This may help, but I assume that you want to keep the 10-bit color depth in your files? If you're converting, you might as well convert to HEVC – I wouldn't recommend converting to 8-bit H.264.

Comment: 980 Ti has 2 nvenc chips as per the given link - see the complete tables.

Comment: thanks -vcodec hevc -crf 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le was what worked for me and just left a queue running

hevc_nvenc does work as I got it working simply using handbrake but it seems to have quality issues and introduces jerkiness to panning shots by default but it does triple my encoding speed

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, did not see that button. Corrected.

Comment: @JasonWright The quality with NVENC for HEVC should be quite good when setting `-vbr_hq`. You can also play with the presets. If you ask a new question about those settings specifically, it might be possible to improve those options.